# Jenkins web ui is totally unresponsive

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

My jenkins instance has been running for over two years without issue but yesterday quit responding to http requests. No errors, just clocks and clocks.

I've restarted the service, then restarted the entire server.

There's been a lot of mention of a thread dump. I attempted to get that but I'm not sure that this is that.

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 663552K, used 244203K [0x00000000d6700000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 646144K, 36% used [0x00000000d6700000,0x00000000e4df5f70,0x00000000fde00000)
  from space 17408K, 44% used [0x00000000fef00000,0x00000000ff685060,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 17408K, 0% used [0x00000000fde00000,0x00000000fde00000,0x00000000fef00000)
 ParOldGen       total 194048K, used 85627K [0x0000000083400000, 0x000000008f180000, 0x00000000d6700000)
  object space 194048K, 44% used [0x0000000083400000,0x000000008879ee10,0x000000008f180000)
 Metaspace       used 96605K, capacity 104986K, committed 105108K, reserved 1138688K
  class space    used 12782K, capacity 14961K, committed 14996K, reserved 1048576K
```

Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Comment: in my case, the server has a very limited memory

Answer (score 0):

I prefer looking in the jenkins log file. There you can see error and then fix them.

Comment: Full Harddisk? What does Clocks mean in you original post?